# How to access and store selected fields from a dynamic structure in matlab?

Tags: matlab, structure, matlab-struct

I have a huge dynamic structure. It looks something like this:

```
s.one.name = 'Mr. Doe';
s.one.time = '12:00';
s.one.ID = '209';
s.one.data = 'Data1';

s.two.name = 'Ms. Jane';
s.two.time = '13:00';
s.two.ID = '210';
s.two.data = 'Data2';

s.three.name = 'Ms. Alice';
s.three.time = '14:00';
s.three.ID = '212';
s.three.data = 'Data3';

s.four.name = 'Mr. Smith';
s.four.time = '14:00';
s.four.ID = '212';
s.four.data = 'Data4';
```

Now, I want to access and store only the first two fields `one` and `two` (out of all the given fields) and its corresponding data into a new dynamic structure `snew`.

I have tried doing the following things:

```
for ii = 1:2
    snew = [s.(ii)];
end
```

Error: `Argument to dynamic structure reference must evaluate to a valid field name.`

Could anyone help me out in acheiving this task?

Thank you in advance

Comment: The notation `s.(ii)` implies that `ii` is a character vector containing the *name* of the field you want to access, which is why your code generates the error shown. If you just access `s.one` or `s.two` you will get a struct containing the four fields from `s.one` or `s.two` respectively. It's not clear to me exactly what you want `snew` to contain though - can you show us?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For two fields you can do it stright forward:

```
snew = struct('one', s.one, 'two', s.two);
```

for variable number of fields (say k) you can do it as following:

```
names = fieldnames(s);
vals = struct2cell(s);
list = [names(1:k) vals(1:k)]';
snew = struct(list{:});
```

Answer (score 0):

You want a vector of structs:

```
s(1) = struct()
s(1).name = 'Mr. Doe'

...

s(2) = struct()
s(2).name = 'Ms. Jane'
...
```

then you can access the vector of structs using indexing:

```
snew = s(i)
```

if you want only the first two *members* you can do:

```
snew = s(1:2)
```

Comment: You're suggesting that the questioner changes how they are storing the data in the first place, which may be a good idea if they can do so, but in the example data shown above, `s` has only one member and it seems they want to access all the fields in `s.one` and `s.two` respectively.

Comment: @nekomatic Yes - it seems more likely that restructuring in a way as I have suggested is a better approach than sticking with the original storage method.

Answer (score 0):

You can put the fields you want to copy in a cell array and then loop through that and access struct fields via dynamic field names.

```
to_keep = {'one', 'two'};

out = struct();

for k = 1:numel(to_keep)
    out.(to_keep{k}) = s.(to_keep{k});
end
```

As others have noted, there is probably a better way to organize your data to make this operation simpler.